# Unable to select complete text in jQuery editable on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a plugin jquery.editable-1.3.3.min.js and I am creating the editable input control like

```
HTML:
<h6 id="editable_field">Add Note Here...</h6>

JS:
 $('#editable_field').editable();
```

Following is JS I am having problem with

```
$('#editable_field').click(function () {
            $(this).select();
        });
```

So the above js is not working meaning - as soon as i click on editable_field, its all contents are not getting selected. Any workaround ?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myx4m8o2/1/)
On Click, I want the entire text to be selected/highlighted

Comment: edited to point to correct url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is select the `input` instead of the `h6` like so:

HTML

```
<h6 id="editable_field">Add Note Here...</h6>
```

JS

```
$('#editable_field').editable(); 

$('#editable_field').click(function () {
    $(this).find('input').select();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myx4m8o2/1/)

**EDIT**: 
This is definately a bit hacky... but it works [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1cr6dem/)

```
$('#editable_field').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() { $('#editable_field input').select(); }, 0);
});
```

## Final code :

HTML

```
<h6 id="editable_field">Add Note Here...</h6>
```

JS

```
$('#editable_field').editable(); 

$('#editable_field').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() { $('#editable_field input').select(); }, 0);
});
```

Comment: I observed it works for first time, but not next time onwards

Comment: What about the latest version with the `setTimeout`? Thats working for me consistently.

Comment: I figured that it was probably trying to select the text before `jquery.editable` had created the `input`. So I initially tried with a 100ms delay and then reduced it to see if it still worked; which it did :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use the <input> tag, i.e.

```
<h6 id="editable_field">Add Note Here...</h6>
```

should have been

```
<input id="editable_field">Add Note Here...</input>
```

Comment: Worth it explaining that: _The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes._ [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/select/)

Comment: well that doesn't work either, on doing that, the text gets selected for a moment and then selection/highlighting disappears. I want it to stay - and - most probably it dissapears due to editable() function

Comment: @MelanciaUK - I am using type="hidden" as I want to show input textbox only on some other event - wont it work then ?

Comment: @comeOnGetIt Include the exact thing you want to achieve in your question instead of here and there

Comment: With your updated question, you can try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevinle/myx4m8o2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Text selection should happen after the input is created by jquery.editable. Jquery.editable will create input on click of  as it is bound to id of . Hence, a timer is required to allow sufficient time for editable to create input and then fire javascript function to select text in newly created input

```
<h6 id="editable_field">Add Note Here...</h6>
$('#editable_field').editable(); 

$('#editable_field').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() { $('#editable_field input').select(); }, 0);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1cr6dem/)